# htaccess rewrite only one folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a folder in root with the name "pages", all of the HTML pages are there, now i have a rewrite mod, that delete the folder from url and delete the .php, so www.website.com/pages/index.php, becomes: www.website.com/index.

Now, my problem is all the rest of the folders need to be in the root, and when i try require files from those folders, my rewrite mod looking for folders in "pages" folder and not on the root folder.

I need the rewrite mod only on "pages" folder as only those will be used, in the url.

.htacces file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/*$ $1.php [L,QSA]

#remove subfolder pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)pages 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1 [L]
```

Any help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for existence of the php file using a `RewriteCond` and then forward to `pages/` like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /GP/

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/GP/pages/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ pages/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/GP/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: tried, root/new | root/new.php | root/pages/new all failed. only root/pages/new.php worked

Comment: I also asked what is location of above .htaccess

Comment: really? root = localhost/GP, the htaccess is in GP folder which is the root, and the rewrite mod is working on the my wamp server

Comment: http://localhost/GP/new  =  "The requested URL /GP/new was not found on this server."

Comment: you misspelled GP as FP, its working now, thanks alot! BTW i didn't -1 you.

Comment: No issues, someone is downvoting my answers without leaving any comment. I will upvote your question.

Comment: one last question, the problem now, that when i try to enter localhost/GP/new.php, i get an error, how can i redirect from new.php to new, without getting the 404 error

Comment: But `localhost/GP/new.php` is indeed incorrect. It should only be `localhost/GP/new` since you're hiding `.php` extension

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer, i changed the redirect rule to this one:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/subdir/$ http://www.mysample.com/
```

so now, its just rewrite the url without the specific subfolder, to the root and don't touch other subfolders.

any reasons not using that rule?